# Symfony 2.1 Forms: Call to undefined method createView()

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle to manage my users, and I am trying to override the profile edit form, following this doc guide https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md
This is my Form type:

```
<?php


namespace Tracker\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as BaseType;

class ProfileFormType extends BaseType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->buildUserForm($builder, $options);

    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tracker_user_profile';
    }


    /**
     * Builds the embedded form representing the user.
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    protected function buildUserForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('avatar','file',array( 'required'=>'true'));
    }
}
```

This is my `services.yml` add:

```
 tracker_user.profile.form.type:
         class: Tracker\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
         arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
         tags:
             - { name: form.type, alias: tracker_user_profile }
```

This is the `config.yml` part for setting up `FOSUSerBundle`

```
profile:
    form:
        type: tracker_user_profile
```

And finally my Controller Action, which i almost copied 1to1 from original FOSUser Controller:

```
/**
 * Edit the user
 */
public function editAction()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    $form = $this->container->get('tracker_user.profile.form.type');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.handler');

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process) {
        $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'profile.flash.updated');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->getRedirectionUrl($user));
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
        'FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

When i call the page, i get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Tracker\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType::createView() in /coding/src/Tracker/UserBundle/Controller/ProfileController.php on line 105

Is there anything wrong with the way i set up the service? or my code?

Comment: yes, i put in the main services.yml file of the whoe project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, retrieve the Form instance instead of the FormType instance:

```
$form = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form');
```